# jQuery: onclick instead of href=javascript::

Tags: jquery

Yes ive been told a couple of time using onclick

```
$('#linkId').click(function()
```

instead of

```
<a href='javascript:showComments($displayWall[id]);'>
```

But then how do i store a variable in the function, like i can do with that above?

I mean if a link is like this: `<a id="linkId">test</a>` where can i store a variable?

Comment: Where does `$displayWall[id]` come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

It looks more like `$displayWall` is a global JS variable (otherwise `<a href='javascript:showComments($displayWall[id]);'>` would not work). Then this should actually work too:

```
$('#linkId').click(function() {
    showComments($displayWall[id]);
});
```

---

I realize now, that the following assumption is far fetched, but nevertheless:

*Assuming `$displayWall` is a server side variable, meaning the page gets pre-processed.*

You could, for example, set the `ref` attribute of the link to the variable value:

```
<a id="linkId" ref="$displayWall[id]">test</a>
```

and access it in the click handler:

```
$('#linkId').click(function() {
    showCmments($(this).attr('ref'));
    //...
});
```

If you are attaching the handler to one element only, you can also set the variable inside the click handler:

```
$('#linkId').click(function() {
    var value = '$displayWall[id]';
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `<a id="linkId" name="SOME_DATA">test</a>`.  In the click handler you can access the data like so:

```
$('#linkId').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other attributes to hold your dynamic value (like id, name, rel, class, etc). One of examples could become like this -> PHP/HTML:

```
echo '<a class="showComments" id="c',$displayWall['id'],'" href="#">Show comments</a>';
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("a.showComments").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(1);
    // ...
    return false;
  });
});
```

If your variable is the same for all elements you can define it as javascript variable.

```
var myVar = "<?=$myVar;?>";
```